How to define a generic type that is generic
I was following this solution here
And I wanted to improve it and make it even more generic. So I came up with this even more generical genric type:
export type extractGeneric<Type, Parent> = Type extends Parent<infer Entity> ? Entity : never

However, typescript is complaining that Type 'Parent' is not generic
Type 'Parent' is not generic.ts(2315)

The official solution requires to hardcode it with Repository as shown below:
import { Repository } from "typeorm"

export type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends Repository<infer Entity> ? Entity : never


Did you read the comments below the answer you linked? This is not possible.

@Bergi, sorry I didn't. Do you think there is a workaround to get it to work? I feel I'm close to the solution but can't guess it

No, I don't think there is a workaround. I don't see what you mean by "close to the solution".

This isn't (currently) possible. Typescript generics have type parameters, not parameters of other kinds, like values or generics. In your desired form Parent has to be a generic, not a type, for Parent<infer Entity> to be valid.
There is a an open issue on the language to allow generics as parameters to other generics, however that is a decade old, and does not seem to be being actively worked on. The proposed syntax would be
export type extractGeneric<Type, Parent<~>> = Type extends Parent<infer Entity> ? Entity : never

